# QGIS how to merge a linestring layer and a point layer into a multigeometry layer

Tags: qgis, merge, multi-geometry

I have two layers:

- Layer1 is point type.
- Layer2 is linestring type.

I need to obtain one unique layer merging both layers. Of course, it will need to be multigeometry type.

Comment: No, it will not be a multigeometry layer but a layer of general geometry type. As far as I know QGIS does not support those. You can do it with Spatilite or OpenJUMP or GDAL by converting and appending both layers into some vector format that supports any type of geometries on the same layer. Shapefiles are out of question but you have many other choices: MapInfo tab, GML, Spatialite, PostGIS, Oracle... Both source layers must naturally have identical schemata.